# Cannot find the Debug Tab for Azure Notifications Hub (New UI)

Tags: android, azure, xamarin, push-notification, azure-notificationhub

I am following this tutorial [Getting started with Azure Notifications Hub for Xamarin.Android](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/partner-xamarin-notification-hubs-android-get-started/)

I have everything setup for my app and now I need to send a test notification to see if my configuration is correct but the Debug tab seems to have gone missing. 
Can anyone point me in the right direction ? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if you're using Visual Studio but if so, you can also use the Server Explorer. Add you Azure subscription there and navigate to the Notification Hub.

From there you have all the functionality which is also available from the Debug tab on Azure.

[image: Notification Hub in Server Explorer]

Checking out the new portal, I think this functionality is (not) yet available.
There *is* however an option to go back to the 'full' Azure portal (which also implicates not everything is available yet).

[image: Go to full Azure Portal]

Another option is to use the Service Bus Explorer, although this application has been giving me some trouble for the past few days.

This option, and all others, are described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/azure/dn530751.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Debug tab is available in old portal (for now I guess) at: `manage.windowsazure.com`
You can also create a postman or fiddler request containing sas token, sample here: https://milenppavlov.wordpress.com/2015/12/15/get-shared-access-signature-authentication-for-azure-notification-hub-and-create-push-notification-via-rest-call/ that can send the notifications for you.